# What class to expect helper method calls on when called from a view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rails-cells

I have a view, that calls a helper. In my rspec tests, I want to check that this helper is called with the appropriate attributes.

```
<div class="chart">
  <%= chart_tag(:pie, {css: 0.1, javascript: 0.3, ruby: 0.6}) %>
</div>
```

I don't want to test that `chart_tag` is rendering the correct HTML; it is a complex helper that sets all kinds of `data-` attributes; it sets highcharts params. This method itself is tested properly.

I want to test something like:

```
expect(TemplateClass::SomeHelper).to receive(:chart_tag).with(:pie)
```

I don't know where to set the expectations on: I don't know how cells renders things. It seems that it leverages rails' rendering stack, but that too is an unfamiliar area for me.

I am calling this through [cells](https://github.com/apotonick/cells), so the generic `rspec view` does not apply here.

In cells, helpers are included with `helper`, which, as far as I can tell, is a [rails method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Helpers/ClassMethods.html#method-i-helper). But following that code, still does not tell me what is included in the view, through what proxy, class or module.

To illustrate part of the stack/code:

```
class AnalysisCell < Cell::Rails
  helper ChartHelper

  def chart(params)
    @type = params[:type] || :pie
    @dataset = params[:dataset] || {}
    render # Cells will now, magically, parse and process app/cells/analysis/chart.html.erb
  end
end
```

`app/cells/analysis/chart.html.erb`

```
<%= debugger %>
<%= chart_tag(:pie, {css: 0.1, javascript: 0.3, ruby: 0.6}) %>
```

`app/helpers/chart_helper.rb`

```
module ChartHelper
  def chart_tag(type, dataset)
  end
end
```

When falling into the debugger, I can inspect the state from within the
`erb`:

```
self.class #=> #<Class:0x007f9eef0215a8>
self._helpers #=> NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `_helpers
self.methods.sort #=>
# [...
# :cell_for,
# :chart_tag,
# :check_box_tag,
# ...]
# self.method(:chart_tag).owner #=> ChartHelper
```

But the test fails with `received: 0 times with any argument`:

```
it 'renders a chart' do
  expect(ChartHelper).to receive(:chart_tag) #.with(:pie, {})
  render_cell(:analysis, :chart, type: :pie, dataset: {})
end
```

Any idea what to test the message-expectation on?

Comment: Blind guess: as the helper is a module, therefore mixed into the renderer class, then its the renderer class who receives the message, not the module. So your expectation should be targeting the renderer

Comment: and another guessing: `chart_tag` is instance method (not class)

Comment: and another guessing: `expect(ChartHelper).to receive(:chart_tag)` should be `expect_any_instance_of(AnalysisCell).to receive(:chart_tag)`

Comment: `expect_any_instance_of(AnalysisCell)` does not match it. Nor does `expect_any_instance_of(Class)`. Somewhere deep down in the render_to_string stack something weird seems to be going on. Diving deeper.

Comment: @gotva: an instance of what? The caller (Cell) or the renderer? And if the renderer, what would be the instance that is to be tested against?

Comment: Difficult to say... (I can't experiment now with similar code). I would say instance of `AnalysisCell` but you have already tried it. What about if try to inspect `self` object where you call `chart_tag`, maybe this helps to find out `self.class`

Comment: @gotva: I've added the `self.class #=> #<Class:0x007f9eef0215a8>` to my question. It reports of being a "class". Not very helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

In my view specs, I would typically write

```
expect(view).to receive(:chart_tag).with(:pie)
```

Comment: Do you use a gem in addition to RSpec? Is view something you defined, or that RSpec recognizes?